# Will a new Stack Frame be created on entering a block of statements?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, do braces act as a stack frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759371/in-c-do-braces-act-as-a-stack-frame)

```
int main()
{
   int i=10;

   {
       int i=100;
       printf("%d", i);
   }
}
```

Will the internal "{" and "}" create a new stack frame?

Comment: You can try to look at [THIS][1]

It's pretty clear.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759371/in-c-do-braces-act-as-a-stack-frame

Comment: @DonCallisto FYI, in comments, you create links like this: `[link_title](http://link-url/)` - this also works in questions.

Answer (score 6):

This is totally implementation dependent, but for implementations out there, the answer is no. The two `i` variables will typically be implemented by two separate variables in the same stack frame, although in this particular case, the first `i` might be omitted altogether.

Creating a stack frame (on i386) is only needed when you call a subroutine (even if it were only for the return address). This doesn't happen in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Only if the compiler is feeling an itch. There's certainly no language requirement involved. to be more specific, I can't think of any reason that any compiler would feel an urge to push a frame here except to optimize storage for a very large number of locals. The compiler is perfectly capable of managing the names without a runtime frame.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps. Perhaps not. The lanaguage does not require it, so the compiler is free to do whatever it wishes.